Парный союз "как... так и..." с тремя и более однородными членами
Верна ли будет верна такая конструкция:
"Как [первый однородный член, существительное], так и [второй однородный член, существительное], [третий однородный член, существительное]"?
Хотелось бы ответ с ссылкой на авторитетный источник.


Авторитетные источники не нашлись, но можно с достаточной степенью уверенности сказать, что вместо запятой во второй части предложения надо использовать одиночный союз И/ИЛИ.  В этом случае двойной союз КАК ...ТАК И свяжет  первый однородный член со вторым и третьим.

Действительно, к предложению из двух однородных членов можно добавить третий, причем в любую его часть, например:
Ему нравится как графика, так и живопись и 
акварель.    
Для озеленения города используются как 
однолетние, так и двулетние и многолетние растения.



Такие примеры не рассматриваются в правилах, так как решение выглядит очевидным.

В то же время через запятую можно добавить еще один однородный член, если использовать присоединительный союз А ТАКЖЕ:
На выставке можно посмотреть как художественную, так и 
документальную прозу, а также книги по истории.



Пример
Для России проблематика положения соотечественников остается в числе приоритетов как в отношениях с Латвией и Эстонией, так и в контактах с профильными международными организациями и ЕС («Дипломатический вестник», 2004)
